# Create custom validation for 2 dropdown list mvc4

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have these two dropdownlist that are supposed to be for age and I want to make it so that you cant make min age higher than max age

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3  editor-group ">
    @Html.Label("Mininum Age")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Preference.MinAgeId, new SelectList(Model.MinAges, "AgeId", "CurAge", Model.Preference.MinAgeId),"-Any-", new { @class = " form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MinAges)
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3  editor-group ">
    @Html.Label("Maximum Age")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Preference.MaxAgeId, new SelectList(Model.MaxAges, "AgeId", "CurAge", Model.Preference.MaxAgeId),"-Any-", new { @class = " form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MaxAges)
</div>
```

I dont know if the way I am creating the dropdownlist makes it possible to flag that is it invalid among each other dropdowns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using this nuget package [MVC Foolproof Validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/). You will be able to do it. If you don't want to use an external libs. You can implement IValidatableObject on your Model and code the validation there.